# Parameters, Unpacking and variables - Learn python the hard way ex 13

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm stuck at this point. here is the code:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "The first variable is:", first
print "The second variable is:", second
print "The third variable is:", third
```

my problem is this, when I run it I get:

> value error need more than one value to unpack

as far as I can see I have three values and the code is good, could someone explain where I am going wrong please.

Comment: show us your call from the cli.

Comment: no not intentional its meant to be lower case

Comment: python ex013.py first, 2nd, 3rd

Comment: confirmed and edited thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in chat @Ricky troubleshooted his way to successfully determining that `argv` was splitting on  **whitespace** and not `,` **comma**. Changing his command line params from

```
$python myprog.py one,two,three
```

to

```
$python myprog.py one two three
```

made everything fine.

For those who wish to learn the mysteries of the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).